# Anchor tag helper not generating correct route with area name MVC Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have anchor tag in my asp.net mvc core application as below

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="School" asp-action="Index">School</a>
```

And configured route as

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=SignIn}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "MyArea",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Above anchor tag is generating url as - `https://localhost:44391/School/Index?area=Admin`
However we expect it should be as - `https://localhost:44391/Admin/School/Index`

If I enter correct url in browser, it is working fine but not sure whats wrong with anchor tag syntax.

Can you please guide if I am missing anything?

Comment: Swap the order of the calls to `MapControllerRoute`.

Comment: Ohh.. It worked.. Thanks for identifying quickly:)

Comment: @KirkLarkin can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742151/anchor-tag-helper-withing-area-folder-not-generating-route-area-name-mvc-core-3