# Anchor tag helper withing area folder not generating route area name MVC Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have `Areas` in application. One area name is `Admin` and it has `SchoolController` inside its controller folder and `Views` inside `Views\School folder`.
When I use anchor tag inside `Views\School\Index.html` it is not working i.e not generating href attribute  but if I place the same tag on layout or any other razor page which is not inside area, it is generating href tag.
Anchor tag is -

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="School" asp-action="Index">School</a>
```

Routing configuration is as -

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "MyArea",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=School}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=SignIn}/{id?}");
                
            });
```

Anchor tag rendered out side of area pages as `<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Admin">School</a>` and inside area views as `<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="School" asp-action="Index">School</a>`
Can you please guide whats missing?

Comment: Have a look at your `_ViewImports.cshtml` files. It's likely you don't have an `@addTagHelper` directive for the MVC tag-helpers that's being picked up in areas.

Comment: Got it. I added _ViewImports.cshtml inside areas View folder. Is there any way we can use only one _ViewImports.cshtml file across the application which can be applicable to area views as well?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#_viewimportscshtml

Comment: Glad you got sorted - Also be aware that the controller class may need a [Area("Admin")] attribute too which if missing can cause routing issues, especially if you have actions with the same name as other area controllers

Answer (score 1):

please add

- _ViewImports.cshtml
- _ViewStart.cshtml

inside Area folder too